# Is it normal to modularize/namespace deeply in Rails? My company's code base goes 4 to 5 namespaces deep and I'm wondering if that's normal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I'm a junior Rails developer. I'm finding namespaces 4 and 5 modules/classes deep in my company's code base. It feels like a significant code smell and feels like it makes the code a headache to understand, but I'm new at Ruby/Rails. Here's an example copied, with names changed:

```
class X
  module Y
    module Z
      module A
        class MainClass < X::Y::B::C
          MESSAGE = 'Error Message here'
          def initialize
            super(X::Y::Z::A::MainClass::MESSAGE)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This kind of stuff is all over our code base. Notice: The actual class itself is 4 lines long.
What's stopping someone from namespacing every ASCII character and building off a fully decomposed ASCII character set?
I was wondering if this kind of heavy decomposition/deep namespacing is normal from a more experienced Rails dev's perspective.

Comment: It looks excessive to me, but like anything quantitative about code it really depends on the size and nature of the problem. Are there enough modules/classes in each namespace to justify its existence? What are some examples of actual namespaces?

Comment: Yeah, so I see whats happening. They're drying up Form Objects so that there's not a million line long Class.  It makes sense the more I'm looking at it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick - good to see you again.

Recently, I'm finding that almost all my code is one-to-three 'levels' deep. So:

```
  module Foo
    module Bar
      module Baz
      end
    end
  end
```

or

```
  module Foo
    module Bar
      class Baz
      end
    end
  end
```

If I find myself with more 'levels', then I usually find an opportunity for refactoring lurking somewhere in the code. But, I'm not philosophical or religious on this. It's just the way it seems to turn out.

Comment: Hey J.  Thanks for the response.  Sorry for the delay, got overwhelmed at work.  What was going on in the example I posted is that the dev's were trying to DRY up Form Objects so that there's not a single huge class. I see the purpose now. Also starting to see the appeal of modules/namespaces. It allows alot of flexibility.